# Problem with animation and clicking on links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this webpage (this is demo /prview my code): http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

I make my project in Bootstrap 4.

This is work fine, but I have 2 small errors with Cookies Box:

1. The animation goes from left to right (which is ok) - but then it goes back to the left again (which is wrong). I would like the animation to stay in the position where it is at the end
2. https://ibb.co/pvFzJZZ - The area next to my cookie message is not clickable. It is like a "transparent" mask that prevents clicking. How can this be fixed?

My code:

```
<div class="d-flex container mt-5 cookies-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center card cookie p-3">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center"><img src="images/cookie.png" width="40">
                        <div class="ml-2 mr-2"><span>Ta strona używa cookies. Korzystając ze strony wyrażasz zgodę na
                                używanie cookie, zgodnie z aktualnymi ustawieniami przeglądarki. Korzystanie z naszej
                                strony internetowej bez zmiany ustawień dotyczących cookies oznacza, że będą one
                                zapisane w pamięci urządzenia. Więcej informacji można znaleźć w naszej <br></span><a
                                class="learn-more" href="#" Polityce prywatności.<i
                                class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fullpage">


        <section class="offer section">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sampole txt</h1>

                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/strony_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/systemy_dedykowane.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-5">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/serwery_i_hosting.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/sklepy_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/gry_przegladarkowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/systemy_dedykowane.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    vxxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/portale_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!--            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">-->
                    <!--                <a href="#">-->
                    <!--                    <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">-->

                    <!--                        <img src="images/png/img42.png" class="d-block pr-3" alt="strony internetowe" width="80"-->
                    <!--                             height="auto">-->
                    <!--                        <div class="media-body pr-3">-->
                    <!--                            Aplikacje dla urzędów i instytucji-->


                    <!--                        </div>-->
                    <!--                    </div>-->
                    <!--                </a>-->
                    <!--            </div>-->

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/serwery_i_hosting.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/aplikacje_mobilne.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/konsulting_i_analizy.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/fotografia_reklamowa.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/opieka_techniczna.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/aplikacje_dla_urzedow_i_instytucji.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 pb-4 text-center">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center media-more p-3">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    Zobacz naszą pełną ofert
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
```

My css: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/css/style.css

How can I repair it?
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the suspect for the 'transparent background' is the `display: flex`. This is because the `flex` in your container will attempt to fill the entire width of the parent. Which in this case is the body and so the element overlaps the entire width of the body.

As for the animation, a `left` value for the cookies box isn't set. This will result in it moving back to the start of your container once the animation is complete because no left value is given to the cookies box.

You want to match the `left: 10%` given in your animation.

```
.cookies-box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 10%;
  max-width: 500px;
  left: 10%;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;

  /*for firefox*/
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;

  /* for opera*/
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-name: slidein;

  /* Standard syntax*/
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
```

You'll also want to remove your `col-md-6`.

Using your code supplied, it looks like the following:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --colorWhite: #ffffff;
  --colorMerc: #09d2f0;
  --colorText: #2b2b2b;
  --colorOffer: #e0e0e0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Regular"), url("../font/Now-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Thin";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Thin"), url("../font/Now-Thin.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Light";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Light"), url("../font/Now-Light.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Medium";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Medium"), url("../font/Now-Medium.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Bold"), url("../font/Now-Bold.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Now Black";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Now Black"), url("../font/Now-Black.woff") format("woff");
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--colorText);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: var(--colorText);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--colorMerc);
}

.language-box,
.language-box2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.language-box a {
  font-family: "Now Regular";
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.language-box2 a {
  font-family: "Now Regular";
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.language-box2 a:hover,
.language-box a:hover {
  color: #0ad3f1;
}

.fb {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-link:hover .fb:hover {
  border: 3px solid #0ad3f1;
  color: #0ad3f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-logo{
  filter: invert(0%) sepia(2%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(190deg) brightness(98%) contrast(104%);
}

.greyscale {
  filter: brightness(50%) !important;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%) !important;
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%) !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
.greyscale:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: #00000099;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-toggler {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar-toggler .line {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Now Medium";
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #0ad3f1;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .order-visit {
  color: #0ad3f1;
  border: 2px solid #0ad3f1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .order-visit {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-item {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

/*offer*/

.offer {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.offer h1 {
  font-family: "Now Bold";
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.offer h2 {
  font-family: "Now Bold";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.offer h3 {
  font-family: "Now Regular";
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.offer-list {
  font-family: "Now Regular";
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--colorOffer);
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 105px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.offer-list:hover {
  color: var(--colorMerc);
  border: 2px solid var(--colorMerc);
}

.media-body {
  width: auto;
}

.media-more {
  font-family: "Now Medium";
  line-height: 70px;
  color: var(--colorMerc);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid var(--colorMerc);
  font-size: 22px;
}

.media-more:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/*offer-page*/

.offer-details-all {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.offer-details-all {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.offer-details-all1 {
}

.offer-details-top {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

@media (min-width: 276px) {
  .offer-details-top {
    line-height: 0.9;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .offer-details-top {
    line-height: 0.9;
  }
}

.offer-details {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.offer-more {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: var(--colorMerc);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid var(--colorMerc);
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*onas*/

.text-1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .offer-more {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .offer-more-right {
    float: right;
  }
}

.offer-more:hover {
  color: var(--colorWhite);
  background-color: var(--colorMerc);
}

.brand-logo {
  width: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .brand-logo {
    width: 290px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .brand-logo {
    width: 364px;
  }
}

#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
  background: #09d3f1 !important;
  border: 1px solid #989898;
}

/*#fp-nav ul li a span, .fp-slidesNav ul li a span{*/
/*    background: #ffffff !important;*/
/*    border: 2px solid #7E7E7E;*/
/*}*/

#fp-nav ul li a span {
  border: 1px solid #989898 !important;
  width: 13px !important;
  height: 13px !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 276px) {
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}

/*.carousel-caption{*/
/*    bottom: 50%;*/
/*}*/

/*.carousel-item {*/
/*    height:100vh;*/
/*    min-height: 350px;*/
/*    background: no-repeat center center scroll;*/
/*    -webkit-background-size: cover;*/
/*    -moz-background-size: cover;*/
/*    -o-background-size: cover;*/
/*    background-size: cover;*/
/*}*/

#carousel .carousel-item.slide1 {
  background-image: url("../images/slide.jpg");
}

#carousel .carousel-item.slide2 {
  background-image: url("../images/slide2.jpg");
}

#carousel .carousel-item.slide3 {
  background-image: url("../images/slide.jpg");
}

#carousel .carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*#carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item {*/
/*    transition: -webkit-transform 8s ease;*/
/*    transition: transform 8s ease;*/
/*    transition: transform 8s ease, -webkit-transform 8s ease;*/
/*    transition-duration: 8s;*/
/*}*/

#carousel .carousel-item .caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

#carousel .caption h2 {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#carousel .caption p {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

#carousel .caption a {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.separator {
  -webkit-mask: url(../images/szymon/triangle.svg) no-repeat center;
  mask: url(../images/szymon/triangle.svg) no-repeat center;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 278px !important;
  height: 139px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9;
}

.back-to-top {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 125px;
  right: 125px;
  display: none;

  z-index: 999;
}

.card {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgb(249, 249, 250);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(212, 182, 212, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgb(161, 163, 164);
}

.learn-more {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.learn-more:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.cookies-box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 10%;
  max-width: 500px;
  left: 10%;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;

  /*for firefox*/
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;

  /* for opera*/
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-name: slidein;

  /* Standard syntax*/
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }

  to {
    left: 10%;
  }
}



@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .shrink {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .shrink .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #7d7d7d;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .shrink .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link .fb{
    color: #000000;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
  }
}



.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .order-visit {
  color: #0ad3f1;
  border: 2px solid #0ad3f1;
}

.brand-logo-black{
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(167deg) brightness(106%) contrast(105%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container mt-5 cookies-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center card cookie p-3">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center"><img src="images/cookie.png" width="40">
                        <div class="ml-2 mr-2"><span>Ta strona używa cookies. Korzystając ze strony wyrażasz zgodę na
                                używanie cookie, zgodnie z aktualnymi ustawieniami przeglądarki. Korzystanie z naszej
                                strony internetowej bez zmiany ustawień dotyczących cookies oznacza, że będą one
                                zapisane w pamięci urządzenia. Więcej informacji można znaleźć w naszej <br></span><a
                                class="learn-more" href="#" Polityce prywatności.<i
                                class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fullpage">


        <section class="offer section">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sampole txt</h1>

                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/strony_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/systemy_dedykowane.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-5">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/serwery_i_hosting.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/sklepy_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/gry_przegladarkowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/systemy_dedykowane.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    vxxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/portale_internetowe.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!--            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">-->
                    <!--                <a href="#">-->
                    <!--                    <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">-->

                    <!--                        <img src="images/png/img42.png" class="d-block pr-3" alt="strony internetowe" width="80"-->
                    <!--                             height="auto">-->
                    <!--                        <div class="media-body pr-3">-->
                    <!--                            Aplikacje dla urzędów i instytucji-->


                    <!--                        </div>-->
                    <!--                    </div>-->
                    <!--                </a>-->
                    <!--            </div>-->

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/serwery_i_hosting.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/aplikacje_mobilne.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/konsulting_i_analizy.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/fotografia_reklamowa.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/opieka_techniczna.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 pb-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center offer-list p-3">
                                <img src="images/szymon/icons/aplikacje_dla_urzedow_i_instytucji.svg" class="pr-3"
                                    title="xxxxxx lorem ipsum ">
                                <div class="media-body pr-3">
                                    xxxxxx lorem ipsum
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 pb-4 text-center">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="media align-items-center media-more p-3">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    Zobacz naszą pełną ofert
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
```

For more information on flex, [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)!